# HTTP ERROR 500 Trying to consult a .mdb Microsoft Access database using PHP

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

Friends I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database using PHP, on my computer using XAMPP it connects perfectly and I can make queries without problems.

The problem is when I want to do it in my hosting I get the following error:

[image: HTTP ERROR 500]

As I tried to change the file permissions to ** 777 ** because I thought it was because of that and I still can not solve this problem

This is my code:

```html
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/cookies/printSaver.mdb";
//home/ezujjnuo/example.com/cookies/printSaver.mdb
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("No found.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
$productId = "Rafael Dorado";
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Prints";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();
$productPrice = $row["Owner"];
$productPriced = $row["Printed"];
echo $productPrice;
echo $productPriced;
?>
```

And this is my database:

[image: database]

This is my PHPinfo;

[image: pdo_enabled]

Error_log:

[image: error_log]

I already tried placing the file permissions on 777 but it has not worked

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: And run `phpinfo()` to ensure that your server's installation actually has the modules you need.

Comment: I have added more information

Comment: That ODBC driver is only available for Windows not any other OS. You need a special driver for other OS's to connect to MS Access.

Comment: @Parfait that makes sense to me